# How can I display a frontmatter array with Next.js and Mdx?

Tags: arrays, next.js, markdown

I'm working on a project in Next.js where I have to display a bullet list from an array in frontmatter.

I managed to display the list, but the bullets are empty. How can I fix this?

This is my code:

Template.js:

```
{frontMatter.arrays.map(({ array }) => (
    <li>{array}</li>
))}
```

page.mdx:

```
arrays:
 - Content 1
 - Content 2
```

Result:

[image: Result array]

Answer (score 1):

Write your array like this in your frontmatter

```
arrays: ['item1', 'item2']
```

then to get the values:

```
{arrays && arrays.map((z) => (
    <p>{z}</p>
))}
```